# Quick Sort Recursion Stack Overflow

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I'm having an issue getting my program to compile due to a stack overflow.

The issue lies on line 206 of the quicksort class.  I'm kind of stuck as to where to go next since this is my second ever course with Java.  Any and all help will be appreciated.  I'll post a snippet and a link to the GitHub repo as well.

https://github.com/das1tmane/Sort-Comparison

Thanks.

````
public class QuickSort
    {
        /*
         * Select the first item of the partition as the pivot. Treat
         * partitions of size one and two as stopping cases.
         */
        public int firstPartition(int arr[], int low, int high)
            {
                int pivot = arr[low];
                int i = (high+1); // index of larger element
                for (int j = high; j > low; j--)
                    {
                        // If current element is smaller than or
                        // equal to pivot
                        if (arr[j] >= pivot)
                            {
                                i--;

                                // swap arr[i] and arr[j]
                                int temp = arr[i];
                                arr[j] = temp;
                            }
                    }

                // swap arr[i-1] and arr[low] (or *pivot*)
                int temp = arr[i - 1];
                arr[low] = temp;

                return i-1;
            }

 public void sort(int arr[], int low, int high, int sortKind)
            {
                // QuickSort type 1; Pivot at first element, 
                if (low < high && sortKind == 0)
                    {
                        int pi = firstPartition(arr, low, high);

                        // Recursively sort elements before
                        // partition and after partition
                        sort(arr, low, pi - 1, 0);
                        sort(arr, pi + 1, low, 0);
                    }
                // Quicksort type 2: stop at partitions of 100, then do
                // insertion sort ```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO. I can see several errors in your code. Have you tried using an interactive debugger to step through and check variables are what you are expecting? I think you'll find the problems pretty quickly if you do that. You also might find it useful to write unit tests for the partitioning code to make sure it's working before trying the sort algorithm.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try the interactive debugger now.

Comment: Even correctly written quick sort code will result in stack overflow with some data patterns if it isn't modified to limit stack space by using recursion on the smaller partition, and looping back to handle the larger partition. This will reduce stack space complexity to O(log(n)), but worst case time complexity remains O(n^2).